# Issue while connection to Mobilefirst Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying "Cordova end-to-end demonstration" demo with the MFP server on Bluemix. When I pressed the button "Ping MobileFirst Server", it always shows "Connecting to Server..." and never change. It seems not run the WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken() function. I am previewing the application in a browser and in the browser's console it is showing "getCachedAccessToken for scope failed: undefined".

Server:

IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Operations Console
Product version: 8.0.0.00-20161122-1902

Comment: If you were to uninstall the application once and try again, does it work?

Comment: I am using browser simulator to preview application. I also tried on device but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `mfpdev app register <your Bluemix Foundation URL>`?
That's gotten me once or twice...  If you leave the servername off the command, it registers to whatever is your default - which is usually `localhost`.  You have to run `mfpdev server add` to create the entry that points to the Bluemix service URL, then then register your app to that named instance.

-Paul-

Comment: HI Paul, Yes I have run mfpdev app register <Bluemix Server UR>